# Is there a way to detect an AssertionError in Ava

Tags: ava

What I want to do is `console.log` something if there is a failure in an AVA test but I can't find any documentation on how to do this - if its possible.

```
test.afterEach.always(t => {
  if(t.hasFailure()){                  //something like this
    console.log(JSON.stringify(t.context.someJSON));
  }   
});

test('it fails', t => {
  t.context.someJSON = {sample: 'object'}
  t.fail('forced failure');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of doing this currently, though we have an issue open for it: https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/840